# Creating a dictionary of dataframe in R

Tags: dataframe, list, function, dictionary, dynamic-programming

I wrote a function to import several Excel workbooks into R dynamically. It works well, and I use a list to keep the dataframe. What I would like is actual dataframes I can use afterward. So I tried adding a dictionary to hold the dataframes but it does not work either. I have done this in Python but I cannot reproduce it in R. Any help is welcome. Thanks.

```
manatee_dob<- function(end){
    listofdfs <- list() #Create a list in which you intend to save your df's.
    # Create dataframe dictionary to store each dataframe
    dobdict_df = {}
    for (count in 1:end) {
        df<- read_excel(paste0("../Data/Public-Manatee2018-page",count,".xlsx"))
        df<- select(df,case_number,party_type,case_type,dob)
        names(df)[1]="Case.Number"
        head(df)
        listofdfs[[count]] <- df # save your dataframes into the list
        dobdict_df[[count]] = df #put dataset into dictionary to access it 
    }
    return(listofdfs) #Return the list of dataframes.
}
```

The resulting dataframes are listed one by one with the call limited to (end=2):  manatee_dob(2)
The problem is I need to combine all the dataframes later into 1 single dataframe and the list items "[[1]]", "[[2]]" etc... are not accessible. See error message.

```
                                                                                                                                                      
[[1]]
# A tibble: 500 × 4
   Case.Number    party_type case_type   dob  
   <chr>          <chr>      <chr>       <chr>
 1 2018MM000001AX Defendant  Misdemeanor 1995 
 2 2018MM000002AX Defendant  Misdemeanor 1965 
 3 2018MM000003AX Defendant  Misdemeanor 1961 
 4 2018MM000004AX Defendant  Misdemeanor 1987 
 5 2018MM000005AX Defendant  Misdemeanor 1973 
 6 2018MM000006AX Defendant  Misdemeanor 1970 
 7 2018MM000007AX Defendant  Misdemeanor 1962 
 8 2018MM000008AX Defendant  Misdemeanor 1992 
 9 2018MM000009AX Defendant  Misdemeanor 1972 
10 2018MM000010AX Defendant  Misdemeanor 1993 
# ℹ 490 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

> print(dobdict_df[1])
Error: object 'dobdict_df' not found
> print([[1]])
Error: unexpected '[[' in "print([["
```

Comment: I updated the function, so now, I use dplyr::bind_rows(listofdfs) instead of a dictionary, which is unnecessary.  The resulting output is all dataframes elements of the list combined into one.